# What material for battery contact spring monitoring temperature device in fridge

Tags: batteries, copper

I have a battery case I am creating for fridge sensor temperature monitoring. For the battery spring contact I am currently using copper tape. Is this an appropriate metal to use? Or should I be concerned about corrosion in a fridge setting that can have condensation and fluctuating temperature? What other alternatives would be more appropriate?

Comment: Gold-plated beryllium copper is a popular material for spring contacts.